# PDF of Beta Distribution written as exponential family form

Tags: generalized-linear-model, density-function, beta-distribution, exponential-family

I am trying to write the pdf of a beta random variable in its biparametric canonic form such as:

**Function 1**
$$
f_Y(y; \theta,   \phi) = exp \{ \phi[y \theta - b(\theta)] + c(y, \phi) \}  \mathbb{1}_A(y) 
$$

My work so far:

First, I use the beta function so facilitate calculation:

$$
B(\alpha, \beta) =\frac{\Gamma(\alpha)\,\Gamma(\beta)}{\Gamma(\alpha+\beta)}
$$

than:

**function 2**
$$
f_Y(y; \alpha,  \beta) = exp\{ - log(B(\alpha, \beta)) + (\alpha - 1)log(y) + (\beta-1)log(1-y)\}\mathbb{1}_{[y \in (0,1)]} 
$$

I defined:

$$
X = [ln(Y), ln(1-Y)]
$$

$$
\theta = [\alpha, \beta]^T
$$

But I am still stuck at this point on figuring out the joint probability density function of $ln(Y)$ and $ln(1-Y)$ and then coming back to $f_Y$.

Comment: Your function 1 does not seem to reflect that the Beta distribution has two parameters, which your function 2 does. Cf the discussion about scalar and vector parameters at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family

Comment: Well, that is the whole question, how to write function 2 as in function 1 format. Function 1 is able to reflect the biparametric beta distribution, actually the function 1 is the well-known Nelder form for biparametric distributions of the exponential family...

Comment: In the link, you find the multiparameter version written in matrix algebra, more specifically with an inner product. You need to multiply and sum the terms of that inner product to get something like in your function 2.